# Emulator android don’t start on meteor

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

After trying this command: meteor run android
I got this result:

```
C:\Users\Houssem\Desktop\test3>meteor run android
[[[[[ C:\Users\Houssem\Desktop\test3 ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
   Type Control-C twice to stop.

Starting Android Emulator
```

i left it all the night and it still in the same position. But when i stop it i got this result:

```
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:

   While running Cordova app for platform Android with options --emulator:
   Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Houssem\Desktop\test3\.meteor\local\cordova-build\platforms\android\cordova\run
   --emulator --emulator
   No emulator specified, defaulting to titanium_1_WVGA800
   ^C
   at ChildProcess.exitCallback (C:\tools\utils\processes.js:151:23)
   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)

C:\Users\Houssem\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.5_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\isopackets\cordova-support\npm\node_modules\meteor\promise\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:165
      throw error;
            ^
ExitWithCode:1
```

Answer (score 0):

From "C:\Users\Houssem\Desktop\test3.meteor\local\cordova-build\platforms\android\cordova\run" I can see you are using windows machine.

> Currently, Meteor on Windows does not support mobile builds